# Valores Booleanos contrários python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

meu df no tem seguintes informações

```
    Data pagamento  Data contábil   Valor   Grupo   Cota    contrato    Data adesão Data vencimento Valor parcela
0     17/11/2022     22/11/2022     627,0    467     154     4046096     26/08/2022     10/11/2022     621.48
```

realizando as comparações abaixo, tenho a seguinte comparação

```
#df_final['teste'] = df_final['Data_pagamento'] <= df_final['Data_contabil']
df_final['teste1'] = df_final['Data_pagamento'] < df_final['Data_adesao']
df_final['teste2'] = df_final['Data_contabil'] < df_final['Data_adesao']
display(df_final)
```

tenho este resultado Final

```
Data_pagamento  Data_contabil   Valor   Grupo   Cota    contrato    Data_adesao Data_vencimento Valor_parcela   teste1  teste2
17/11/2022       22/11/2022     627,0    467     154     4046096    26/08/2022   10/11/2022        621.48        True   True
```

porêm Meus resultados deveriam encotrar False e não True, exsite alguma consideração que deva tomar antes de utilizar os operadores ??

Answer (score -2):

Eu presumo que o erro seja devido a não ter os datatypes corretos. As colunas com data estão em formato datetime?

Um exemplo de como passar para datetime no seu caso é:

```
df_final['Data_contabil'] = pd.to_datetime(df_final['Data_contabil'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Em princípio, estando em datetime dá para comparar facilmente